# Adding labels on map layout legend boxes using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, legend

On a geological map legend, is it possible to automatically add a label (eg. formation abbreviation) inside their respective boxes of map layout legend?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Under the Legend tab of the Layer Properties dialog, check and expand the Text on Symbols option.

[image]

Use the Set Labels from Expression button to open an Expression String Builder, where you can select a Field value to use for the text labels or create a more complicated expression, as you would for ordinary layer settings.

[image]

Use the Text Format button to change font size, colour, text buffers etc.

[image]

After setting up the text on symbols in your legend, it can be added to a layout like any other legend.